# Get cumulative distinct count of active ids(ids where deleted date is null as of/before the modified date)

Tags: sql, vertica

I am facing a problem while getting the cumulative distinct count of resource ids as of different modified dates in vertica. If you see the below table I have resource id, modified date and deleted date and I want to calculate the count of distinct active resources as of all unique modified dates. A resource is considered active when deleted date is null as of/before that modified date.

I was able to get the count when for a particular resource lets say resource id 1 the active count(deleted date null) or inactive count(deleted date not null) dont occur consecutively.

But when they occur consecutively I have to take the count as 1 till it becomes inactive and then I have to consider count as 0 for that resource id when it becomes inactive and all consecutive inactive values till it becomes active again. Likewise for all the distinct resource ids and cumulative sum of those.

| sa_resource_id | modified_date | deleted_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-22 15:46:06.758 |  |
| 2 | 2022-01-22 15:46:06.758 |  |
| 16 | 2022-04-22 15:46:06.758 |  |
| 17 | 2022-04-22 15:46:06.758 |  |
| 18 | 2022-04-22 15:46:06.758 |  |
| 16 | 2022-04-29 15:46:06.758 | 2022-04-29 15:46:06.758 |
| 17 | 2022-04-29 15:46:06.758 | 2022-04-29 15:46:06.758 |
| 1 | 2022-05-22 15:46:06.758 | 2022-05-22 15:46:06.758 |
| 2 | 2022-05-22 15:46:06.758 | 2022-05-22 15:46:06.758 |
| 1 | 2022-05-23 22:16:06.758 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-24 22:16:06.758 | 2022-05-24 22:16:06.758 |
| 1 | 2022-05-25 22:16:06.758 |  |
| 1 | 2022-05-27 22:16:06.758 |  |

This is the partition and sum query I have tried out where I partition the table based on resource ids and do sum over different modified dates.

```sql
SELECT md, 
           dca_agent_count 
FROM 
(
    SELECT modified_date AS md,
        SUM(SUM(CASE WHEN deleted_Date IS NULL     THEN 1 
                     WHEN deleted_Date IS NOT NULL THEN -1 ELSE 0 
                END)) OVER (ORDER BY modified_date) AS dca_agent_count
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT sa_resource_id, 
            modified_date, 
            deleted_Date, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY sa_Resource_id, deleted_Date 
                ORDER BY modified_date desc
            ) row_num 
        FROM mf_Shared_provider_Default.dca_entity_resource_raw
        WHERE sa_ResourcE_id IS NOT NULL 
        AND sa_resource_id IN ('1','2','34','16','17','18') 
    ) t
    GROUP BY modified_date
    ORDER BY modified_Date
) b
```

Current Output:

| md | dca_agent_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-22 15:46:06.758 | 2 |
| 2022-04-22 15:46:06.758 | 5 |
| 2022-04-29 15:46:06.758 | 3 |
| 2022-05-22 15:46:06.758 | 1 |
| 2022-05-23 22:16:06.758 | 2 |
| 2022-05-24 22:16:06.758 | 1 |
| 2022-05-25 22:16:06.758 | 2 |
| 2022-05-27 22:16:06.758 | 3 |

If you see the output above all the values are correct except for the last row 27-05-2022 where i need to get count 2 only instead of 3

How do I get the cumulative distinct count of sa resource ids as of the modified dates based on deleted date condition(null/not null) and count should not change when deleted date (null/not null) occur consecutively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, a `DATE` has no hours, minutes, seconds, let alone second fractions, so I renamed the time containing attributes to `%_ts`, as they are `TIMESTAMP`s.

I had to completely start from scratch to solve it.

I think this is the first problem I had to solve with as much as 5 Common Table Expressions:

1. Add a Boolean `is_active` that is never NULL
2. Add the previous obtained `is_active` using `LAG()`. NULL here means there is no predecessor for the same resource id.
3. remove the rows whose previous `is_active` is equal to the current `is_active`.
4. `UNION SELECT` the positive `COUNT DISTINCT`s of the active rows and the negative `COUNT DISTINCT`s of the inactive rows. This also removes the last timestamp.
5. get the distinct timestamps from the original input for the final query

The final query takes CTE 5 and `LEFT JOIN`s it with CTE 4, making a running sum of the obtained distinct counts.

Here goes:

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                                                                      
-- not part of the final query: this is your input data
indata(sa_resource_id,modified_ts,deleted_ts) AS (
          SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2022-01-22 15:46:06.758',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2022-01-22 15:46:06.758',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 16,TIMESTAMP '2022-04-22 15:46:06.758',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 17,TIMESTAMP '2022-04-22 15:46:06.758',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 18,TIMESTAMP '2022-04-22 15:46:06.758',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 16,TIMESTAMP '2022-04-29 15:46:06.758',TIMESTAMP '2022-04-29 15:46:06.758'
UNION ALL SELECT 17,TIMESTAMP '2022-04-29 15:46:06.758',TIMESTAMP '2022-04-29 15:46:06.758'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2022-05-22 15:46:06.758',TIMESTAMP '2022-05-22 15:46:06.758'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,TIMESTAMP '2022-05-22 15:46:06.758',TIMESTAMP '2022-05-22 15:46:06.758'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2022-05-23 22:16:06.758',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2022-05-24 22:16:06.758',TIMESTAMP '2022-05-24 22:16:06.758'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2022-05-25 22:16:06.758',NULL
UNION ALL SELECT 1,TIMESTAMP '2022-05-27 22:16:06.758',NULL
)
-- real query starts here, replace the following comma with "WITH" ...
,
-- need a "active flag" that is never null
w_active_flag AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , (deleted_ts IS NULL) AS is_active
  FROM indata
)
,
-- need current and previous is_active to filter ..
w_prev_flag AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , LAG(is_active) OVER w AS prev_flag
  FROM w_active_flag
  WINDOW w AS(PARTITION BY sa_resource_id ORDER BY modified_ts)
)
,
-- use obtained filter arguments to filter out two consecutive 
-- active or non-active rows for same sa_resource_id
-- this can remove timestamps from the final result
de_duped AS (
  SELECT
    sa_resource_id
  , modified_ts
  , is_active
  FROM w_prev_flag
  WHERE prev_flag IS NULL OR prev_flag <> is_active
)
-- get count distinct "sa_resource_id" only now
,
grp AS (
  SELECT
    modified_ts
  , COUNT(DISTINCT sa_resource_id) AS dca_agent_count
  FROM de_duped
  WHERE is_active
  GROUP BY modified_ts
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    modified_ts
  , COUNT(DISTINCT sa_resource_id) * -1 AS dca_agent_count
  FROM de_duped
  WHERE NOT is_active
  GROUP BY modified_ts
)
,
-- get back all input timestamps in a help table
tslist AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    modified_ts
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  tslist.modified_ts
, SUM(NVL(dca_agent_count,0)) OVER w AS dca_agent_count
FROM tslist LEFT JOIN grp USING(modified_ts)
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY tslist.modified_ts);
-- out        modified_ts       | dca_agent_count 
-- out -------------------------+-----------------
-- out  2022-01-22 15:46:06.758 |               2
-- out  2022-04-22 15:46:06.758 |               5
-- out  2022-04-29 15:46:06.758 |               3
-- out  2022-05-22 15:46:06.758 |               1
-- out  2022-05-23 22:16:06.758 |               2
-- out  2022-05-24 22:16:06.758 |               1
-- out  2022-05-25 22:16:06.758 |               2
-- out  2022-05-27 22:16:06.758 |               2
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. there is only one problem there. the count of 2022-05-27 should come as two only and not three since it is the same resource id 1 which was active on 2022-05-25 as well. hence if deleted date is null for a resource in consecutive days i.e. here it is 25th and 27th then even for 27th we have to get the count as 2 @marcothesane

Comment: thanks @marcothesane for the solution to the problem